# Como depurar código com o formato Object Initializer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, estilo-de-codificação, debug

Seguindo algumas boas práticas que o próprio Visual Studio recomenda, não conseguimos depurar valores de um objeto um a um utilizando o "Inicializador de Objeto" ou "Object Initializer". Qual a melhor forma de contornar esta situação?

Ex.:

```
var myObject = new Object 
{ 
   Id = 1, 
   Nome = "Teste" 
}
```

No formato acima, quando colocamos o breakpoint na linha do Id por exemplo, ele consideram o trecho de código como um todo.

Comment: Como assim? Não consegue fazer o quê?

Comment: Quando colocamos o breakpoint, o mesmo considera todo o trecho de código quando declaramos com Object Initializar. Vou melhorar a pergunta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A inicialização de objeto é um facilitador, se deseja depurar este código tem que usar o estilo tradicional. É verdade que o Visual Studio poderia criar uma forma para isto, mas hoje não tem, então se não existir um *plugin* que trate isto de forma diferente, não tem jeito. Faça:

```
var myObject = new Objeto();
myObject.Id = 1;
myObject.Nome = "Teste";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/ObjectInitializationSyntax.cs).

Desta forma cada inicialização ocorrerá em linha específica e poderá colocar *breakpoint* e andar passo a passo.

Eu troquei o nome do tipo porque `Object` já existe no .NET e não possui esses membros.

Isto pode ser configurado:

[image: Configuração de inicializador de objeto no Visual Studio]

Comment: Exatamente @bigown eu já utilizo desta forma que você postou, mas como o Visual Studio me sugere o Inicializador de Objeto, acabo seguindo a dica! Porem perco a depuração linha a linha!

Comment: Concluindo, o único jeito é este que você declarou, correto?

Comment: A não ser que tenha um *plugin* que eu desconheço, já procurei há algum tempo, não tem outro jeito.

Answer (score 4):

Não tem jeito. Só vendo os valores depois que eles foram inseridos no objeto (vide imagem abaixo) ou inicializando da forma usual, que seria:

```
var myObject = new Object();     
myObject.Id = 1;
myObject.Nome = "Teste";
```

Assim é possível acompanhar linha após linha.

Se você tiver preenchendo propriedades com retornos de métodos, pode sempre entrar no método usando a tecla <kbd>**F11**</kbd> e debuggar o próprio método. Caso contrário, dificilmente vai ser necessário acompanhar o preenchimento linha a linha.

---

[image: Visualização das propriedades depois de preenchidas no objeto]

Comment: Mas quando temos uma inicialização com muitas propriedades fica inviável pois não vou saber aonde está ocorrendo a exceção! Consegue me entender?

Comment: Você não falou em exceção na pergunta, @miltoncamara. Se estiver iniciando propriedades com valores provindos de retorno de método, pode adentrar no método usando F11

Comment: Da forma que você postou a imagem acima, é possível entrar na inicialização do objeto analisando propriedade por propriedade à medida que for atribuindo os valores?

Comment: Só se tiver usando algum método na atribuição. Ex.: `UserId = GetUserId()`. Aí você pode entrar no método `GetUserId` durante o debug

Answer (score 1):

Existe um conceito dentro de `OO` que diz que o ideal é que a sua classe altere ela mesmo e não externamente. Sugiro que para que consiga depurar o código e respeitar essa regra, use o construtor para inicializar os valores.

```
public class Object
{
    public Object(int id, string nome)
    {
        Id = id;
        Nome = nome;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Nome { get; private set; }
}

var myObject = new Object(1, "teste");
```

Comment: Mesmo para DTO's?

Comment: E se precisar alterar uma propriedade faz o quê?

Comment: aí você cria um método público como por exemplo SetNome(string nome); Dessa maneira a sua classe continuara respeitando a regra e alterando ela mesmo e você continua conseguindo depurar.

Comment: @AyrtonGiffoni O próprio compilador cria métodos públicos pra modificar as propriedades. Fazer isso que você disse é redundância e prolixidade.

Comment: redundante? note que eu não disse que é errado, somente informei um conceito de Orientação a Objetos e através dele, sugeri uma maneira de fazer. Dessa maneira, uma classe externa JAMAIS modificará as propriedades dessa classe.

Comment: Isso, redundante. Eu também não disse que é errado. Usando uma propriedade (note que eu disse propriedade e não campo), uma classe externa também **jamais** vai alterar um membro da classe. A diferença é que isso é simplificado.